# Why is "Smooth" shading slower than "Flat" shading in the viewport?

Tags: 3d-view, opengl, opencl

When I set a Mesh to shade as "Smooth" vs "Flat" on a high-poly Mesh Object (such as one with a subdivision modifier), it makes Blender much slower than normal, sometimes almost unusable.

Why does this occur?

Comment: voted as nonconstructive - any number of reasons hardware can perform worse it depends a lot on details of your config, draw modes, drivers, hardware. In some cases there are known limits which can be documented but dont think this is one of them, also blender doesnt use pixel shaders for solid drawing.

Comment: IMHO this should be left open. Instead, it should be edited to address a specific, concrete question regarding shaders and performance.

Comment: I agree that this should be left open: Part of the question the OP is asking (unwittingly?) is "should I be worried about this?" What makes this question useful, IMO, is discovering "Oh yeah, smooth shading on 10,000 polys is really expensive, a slowdown is totally understandable" versus "No...that really shouldn't happen, you're running into a hardware limitation or you have a problem." This can be a really important detail for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't know how many polys you are talking about, and what hardware you are using, there is a general answer that smooth shading is always slower than flat.  Flat shading uses one normal per face to calculate the color of the entire face.  Smooth shading interpolates between the normals of each vertex to render a smoothly curved face. Since a face is at least 3 vertices (i.e. a triangle) then smooth shading will always be at least 3x as slow as flat.

In most cases, even 3-4x as slow is a matter of milliseconds so you don't really notice, but on older hardware with a ton of faces you certainly could.